# Changing Home Page URL

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, url, site-settings

There is a link to the home page located on the global navigation.  The problem is that I would like to change the URL.  I thought this could be done by going to Site Settings > Title, description link.  There is no option available to change the URL.  I am afraid by changing the URL the link to the page will break.  I am able to change the URL for the Home that appears on the quick launch, but not the global navigation.  Going to 'edit links' on the global navigation does not show 'home' to edit the page. Also, if I go to navigation within Site Settings does not grant the option to change the home URL in the global navigation section.  My guess is this 'home' link is connected to the site collection title.  I may not be correct.  This seems like something simple that should be done.

Is there a way to change the URL without breaking the link?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through Welcome Page option but i guess for that you will need to activate Publishing feature at site level.

The other options are

1. If you want to set a Custom Page as a Home Page in a typical SharePoint Team site, you can simply do that by Opening the Page and selecting Page tab -> Make HomePage button to set this particular page as default Home Page for your site.

[image]

2. Another option to set a Custom Page as Home Page in SharePoint 2013 Team site is by using SharePoint Designer 2013. If you have opened or created a Page in SharePoint Designer then you can right click on the page and select the option “Set as Home Page” to set it as a default home page of your SharePoint site.

[image]

Reference: [How to set home page in SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/09/05/how-to-set-a-page-as-home-page-in-sharepoint-2013-site/)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the location of the page you can set the site home. Go to the site settings->Welcome Page and change the URL to the page you want to set as the Home Link.

Comment: Thank you Sandeep Kandregula.  I do not have "Welcome Page" within my site settings.